# Debugging JNI/C++ Android WHERE is the official document on how to do this?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Everything I have seen points to a blog or something out of date or suggest using DS-5 plugin etc.  I need to know where the official document is showing how to debug android native JNI code.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use ndk-gdb to debug my native code (is included with the NDK), and it works fairly well. A nice example on how to use it is [here](http://vilimpoc.org/blog/2010/09/23/hello-gdbserver-a-debuggable-jni-example-for-android/). Yes, it is another blogpost, but this one does not introduce some hackish mumbo-jumo solution :)

I have not found any official documentation, except the ndk-gdb.html in the docs folder of the NDK.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, then I have heard good things about the [Sequoyah plugin](http://eclipse.org/sequoyah/downloads/).

Comment: The ndk-debug document indicates the following modification below, I don't see in NDK-R7 there is a install-binary.mk there is a build-binary.mk not sure if android still strips out the debug information: build/core/install-binary.mk:29:
ifneq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
    $(hide) $(call cmd-strip, $(PRIVATE_DST)) 
endif

Comment: Also not sure if the NDK needs to be rebuilt after modifying this file or just modify the install-binary.mk

Comment: Well looks like it will show errors but not seeing a way to step thru and see values etc.  Do you know a way?